# create custom menu on blackberry

Tags: blackberry, menu, customization

I create a custom menu in new class extends popupScreen. I went when the user clock on the menu button the menu display. I use this code

```
protected boolean keyDown(int keycode, int time) {
     if(Keypad.KEY_MENU == Keypad.key(keycode))
        {
         UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(getScreen());
            Menu popup = new Menu();
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(popup);
            return true;
        }
        else
        return super.keyDown(keycode, time);
}
```

but I obtain error on this line UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(popup); causes by pushScreen. How can I change this code or there is another method to display this menu.

Comment: write UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(popup);
in EventLock.

Comment: Can you explain me how to do it? I'm beginner on blackberry

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Blackberry, creating, displaying and hiding of Menu is handled by the system; you will be provided with callbacks at appropriate time. The callbacks you will need to code are:

```
public boolean onMenu( int instance )
{

 return true; // Menu is created
}

public void makeMenu( Menu menu, int instance )
{
  MenuItem _desired_menu_item = new MenuItem()
  {
     public void run()
     {

     }
  }
  menu.add( _desired_menu_item );
  super.makeMenu( menu, instance)
}
```

That's it! It would work. Please check Blackberry "UI and Navigation guide" for more details

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
protected boolean keyDown(int keycode, int time) {
     if(Keypad.KEY_MENU == Keypad.key(keycode))
        {
           synchronized (UiApplication.getEventLock())
      {
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(getScreen());
            Menu popup = new Menu();
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(popup);     
      }


            return true;
        }
        else
        return super.keyDown(keycode, time);
}
```